# "cannot find -lc" Compiling via linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I make a premise: I'm a "newborn" in the Linux world, I have very little experience. I decided to switch to this operating system after studying it in a university course and I fell in love with it.
Having said that, let me tell you my problem...
I installed Linux Mint 21.1 initially in dual-boot with a fairly small partition size. To extend the partition I thought of reinstalling it from 0 thus avoiding some problems that were appearing. For university reasons I find myself programming and compiling from a terminal. At the first installation of Linux I managed to install everything necessary and to solve the various problems that arose. On reinstallation, when I try to compile a file from the terminal, I get the following message:

```
gcc -c procedure.c
gcc -c semafori.c
gcc -c prodcons_singolo_buffer.c
gcc -o prodcons_singolo_buffer procedure.o semafori.o prodcons_singolo_buffer.o
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lc: File o directory non esistente
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:4: prodcons_singolo_buffer] Errore
```

In particular, the error Is:

```
usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lc: File o directory non esistente
```

Unfortunately I can't find anything about it on the web. Thank you all for your availability and for any response.

**EDIT:**
This is Makefile:

```
    all: prodcons_singolo_buffer

prodcons_singolo_buffer: procedure.o semafori.o prodcons_singolo_buffer.o
    gcc -o prodcons_singolo_buffer procedure.o semafori.o prodcons_singolo_buffer.o

prodcons_singolo_buffer.o: prodcons_singolo_buffer.c
    gcc -c prodcons_singolo_buffer.c

procedure.o: procedure.h procedure.c
    gcc -c procedure.c

semafori.o: semafori.c semafori.h
    gcc -c semafori.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf prodcons_singolo_buffer
```

Comment: I think your Makefile has messed up the path where the compiler searches for libraries. Show your Makefile. Do you get the same issue if you compile it manually from the command line, like this: `gcc -o prodcons_singolo_buffer procedure.c semafori.c prodcons_singolo_buffer.c` ?

Comment: For the record: it is possible to resize a partition

Comment: Are you sure you have presented the full output of `make`?  The error message does not appear to be consistent with the preceding `gcc` command.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Why do you think that? The preceding command is for linking all the object files together, and it links `libc` by default. The error says that it can't find that library.

Comment: Isn't libc linked implicitly (unless you tell gcc not to)?  What happens if you just remove `-lc`.

Comment: Unfortunately it also happens if I compile manually. I edited the post adding the Makefile too. P.S:I know it is possible to resize partition without formatting but having unallocated space left I thought of formatting linux being still inexperienced.

Comment: If the C compiler can't find the C library, it usually means there's a problem with the installation of the compiler and its auxilliary components.  It's odd that the message mentions `-lc`; that isn't normally mentioned in the message unless the command line uses the option.  Maybe you should use a macro `CC = gcc` and then use `${CC}` or `$(CC)` in the command lines.  Then you can run `make CC='gcc -v'` without editing the file to see what GCC is doing for you.  It will show you where it's looking for libraries, etc.

Comment: Unrelated but make has implicit rules on how to compile c files and how to link the binary.  The all line is rule is not intended correctly and you need a `.PHONY: all clean`.  You should be able to delete all but `prodcons_singolo_buffer: procedure.o semafori.o prodcons_singolo_buffer.o` and the all and clean targets

Comment: @Barmar, mainly because no `-lc` option appears in the command.  Secondarily because even if we suppose that the GCC front end synthesizes a literal `-lc` option for `ld`, there are no other options presented to `gcc` that would modulate GCC's standard link behavior.  The alternative, then, would appear to be "the GCC installation is broken".  That cannot be discounted, of course, but I'll make "user error" my first guess nine times out of ten.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what I have to change to my Makefile. Could you tell me? Sorry again, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @John (and others). `-lc` is added to the command line by the gcc driver. You can see that by giving `gcc` the `-v` option, which will show you the expanded command line options actually being fed to the individual components.

Comment: @JohnBollinger My suspicion is that something screwed up when they reinstalled the OS and libc.a is missing.

Comment: @CastreseBasile: It's not your Makefile. It's your compiler paths. When you reinstalled, you didn't put `libc` where gcc is looking for it. (Or maybe it's not there at all.)

Comment: @rici Okay, this is really curious. Where i can find him? Or maybe,  it where should be? 
In /usr/bin/ld?

Comment: @CastreseBasile: I'd expect it to be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but it depends on your installation.

Comment: On my system, there are 3: `/usr/lib64/libc.a`, `/usr/lib64/libc.so` and `/usr/lib/libc.so`

Comment: @CastreseBasile: I'd expect it to be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but it depends on your distro. (That path is from a debian-based distro. Mint might be different.)

Comment: @rici What is the extension of libc?

Comment: @CastreseBasile: `.so`, for a shared object. That will be a linker script which contains the "real" paths; those are symlinks. It's all a bit complicated.

Comment: Guys thank you all so much for your time. I copied the necessary files from a virtual machine that I had installed on windows and now everything seems to be ok. I am grateful to you!!

Comment: @CastreseBasile  Can you add the output from `ldd /bin/bash` to the question?  That should show a line like `libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (ox00007faee3cfa000)`.  That would be the `libc` shared object that `bash` is using - and that your compiler *should* be able to find.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It might be more useful (or also useful) to add the output from `gcc -v -o hello hello.o` (where `hello.o` was previously compiled from `hello.c`), which will show the `LIBRARY_PATH` actually being used by GCC.

Comment: @AndrewHenle linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe3abfe000)
 libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007fbd13ff8000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbd13dd0000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbd1419e000)

Comment: @CastreseBasile From your comment: "I copied the necessary files from a virtual machine that I had installed on windows and now everything seems to be ok.*  What file(s) did you copy?  If you copied files such as `/lib/libc.so` and/or `/lib/libc.a`, you probably copied 32-bit libraries, which means `gcc` is creating 32-bit binaries on your system, but the `ldd` output shows that you have a 64-bit system, where `gcc`  should be creating 64-bit binaries.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your compiler/library install is borked.

Unrelated but here is how I would write your Makefile (untested).   Let me know when you tried it out and I will delete this answer.

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: prodcons_singolo_buffer

prodcons_singolo_buffer: procedure.o semafori.o prodcons_singolo_buffer.o

procedure.o:  procedure.c procedure.h

semafori.o: semafori.c semafori.h

clean:
    rm -f prodcons_singolo_buffer *.o
```

Comment: 'Makefile:12: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Stop.'

Comment: @CastreseBasile Yes, in front of the rm line should be a tab instead of spaces.  Not sure how to actually do that in the editor here.  Heh.